# What is .word, .data and .text in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I am trying to learn to get a better understanding with assembler

Could someone explain what .data, .word and .text means does in the following code??

I don't get what this is for and what it does in this case

```
   .data
    array:
    .word 0x12121212, 0x23232323, 0x34343434, 0x4, 0x5
    .text
    add_array:
    li x1, 0x10000000
    add x3, x0, x0
    lw x2, 0(x1)
    add x3, x3, x2
    lw x2, 4(x1)
    add x3, x3, x2
    lw x2, 8(x1)
    add x3, x3, x2
    lw x2, 12(x1)
    add x3, x3, x2
    lw x2, 16(x1)
    add x3, x3, x2
```

Comment: `.data` signals the start of the data section. `.word` is 32 bit of memory, in the code 5 of them make up the `array` named array. Actual code are put into`.text` section. These are assembler directives.

Comment: It should be noted that you can switch between text and data as much as you want.

Answer (score 6):

`.word` is essentially creating some space in memory to hold data. Each item following it is 4 bytes long. It's similar to creating an array:

**Assembly**

```
array:
.word 0x12121212, 0x23232323, 0x34343434, 0x4, 0x5
```

**C**

```
int array[] = {0x12121212, 0x23232323, 0x34343434, 0x4, 0x5};
```

`.text` tells the assembler to switch to the text segment (where code goes), and `.data` tells the assembler to switch to the data segment (where data goes).

Comment: More specifically, `.data` is where *non-zero*, *read-write* data goes.  Other section names include `.rodata` (or `.rdata` on Windows) for read-only data, and `.bss` for zeroed data.

Comment: so .word alone is able to hold 4 bytes? And the bytes are now 0x12.... and so on. But why do we need to do this? And how do I know proceed to use this array? Or is this just ok here are 4 bytes for further use?  Ah well ok, this .word is named with array how could I use this now in assembly? It's RISC-V btw

Comment: I don't see any use of the array in the further code.

Comment: What about .global?

Answer (score 2):

```
.data
```

The `.data` directive starts series of variable declarations. This is sometimes called a *“data segment”*.

```
array:
.word 0x12121212, 0x23232323, 0x34343434, 0x4, 0x5
```

Here a variable named `array` is being declared with five elements, each sized to the target CPU's *word*. A word typically denotes 16 bits (2 bytes) or 32 bits (4 bytes) of memory, depending of the specific CPU's convention. In other words, the `.word` directive allocates memory.

```
.text
add_array:
```

The `.text` directive starts the actual program code, sometimes called a *“text segment”* or *“code segment”*.

Please note different flavors of assembly terminology exist, depending on the CPU family you are working with.